# \\x to \x with python

Tags: python, utf-8, decode, encode

I have a string like this:

```
'\\xac\\x85'
```

and I want to encode these string like this another:

```
'\xac\x85'
```

I tried a lot of things like encode tu utf-8, replace \\x, etc. But when I print the result it always is with \\x.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'\\xac\\x85'` is the literal representation of `'\xac\x85'`. So you dont have to do any translation

```
>>> print ('\\xac\\x85')
\xac\x85
```

Comment: Nitpick: not internal representation, literal representation. Internal representation is something like the bytes corresponding to `005c 0078 0061 0063 005c 0078 0038 0035` or even `0000005c 00000078 00000061 00000063 0000005c 00000078 00000038 00000035`. Literal representation is how strings are written to be understandable to the compiler in code.

Answer (score 0):

I made this function when I had the same issue
I included a little demo! Hope this helps people!

````py
def FixSlash(string):
 strarr = string.split("\\x");
 string = strarr[0]
 for i in strarr[1:]:
  string+=chr(int(i[:2],16))+''.join(i[2:])
 return string```

my_string = FixSlash("my string has '\\xac\\x85' in it")
print(my_string)                  # returns "my string has '¬' in it" \x85 acts like a new line
print(my_string.encode("latin1")) # returns b"my string has '\xac\x85' in it" proving the '\\x' to '\x' was successful!
#TIP: never trust UTF-8 for byte encoding!!
````